# jQuery Slider sends wrong value via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m using the [jQuery Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical) plugin. The current selected value of the slider should be send with AJAX to a server sided script.

At the moment I´ve a wrong behaviour. The current selected value is always one value infront or behind the value which is send with AJAX.

**For example**: If you slide to the value 5/ 50 it will send "6" instead of "5" to the server sided script.

I´ve made a JS [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v9ug5ojz/3/). Just look under the developers network tab.

```
  // Slider Script

    $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min: 1,
        max: 50,
        value: 50,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#amount").val(ui.value);
        },
    });
  
  $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
  
  // Get Response
    $('#slider-vertical').on('slide', getResponse);
    getResponse(0);

    function getResponse() {
        let itemlevel2 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");

        ajaxManager.add({
            type: "GET",
            cache: "true",
            url: "itemscript.php",
            data: {
                "itemlevel": itemlevel2
            },
            success: function (data) {

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correct this behaviour you can use the `stop` event to only make the AJAX call when the slider stops moving. This has the added benefit of not flooding your server with requests for every single value the slider moves through. Try this:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 1,
    max: 50,
    value: 50,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    },
    stop: getResponse
  });

  $("#amount").val($("#slider-vertical").slider("value"));
  getResponse(0);

  function getResponse() {
    let itemlevel2 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
    console.log(itemlevel2);
    // AJAX here...
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #444 !important;
  background: none !important;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  cursor: default;
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none;
}

.ui-widget.ui-widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
  background-color: #353232;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-range-min {
  left: 0;
  background-color: #817373!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<p>
  <label class="item-slider" for="amount">Stufe:</label>
  <input class="item-slider" readonly id="amount">/
  <input class="item-slider" readonly id="amount2" value="50">
</p>
<div id="slider-vertical" style="height: 10px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `slide` event occurs *before* the slider has updated, which gives you the chance to cancel the slide without having to jump through hoops to restore the value.

So your

```
slide: function(e, ui) { ui.value }
```

gives the expected value, but your

```
$('#slider-vertical').on('slide', () => {
    $("#slider-vertical").slider("value")
});
```

gives the *current* value - ie before it has completed the slide

> https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-slide
>
> Triggered on every mouse move during slide. The value provided in the event as ui.value represents the value that the handle will have as a result of the current movement. Cancelling the event will prevent the handle from moving and the handle will continue to have its previous value.

the solution, if you want to continue to use `slide` *[see other answer for recommended alternative event]*, is to use `ui.value` in your own event handler (or add getResponse to the `slide:` setup)

```
$('#slider-vertical').on('slide', getResponse);
function getResponse(e, ui) {
    //let itemlevel2 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
    let itemlevel2 = ui.value;
};
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pnxhrcwa/)